# is an iPhone bought in the US compatible with Germany?

Tags: iphone, apple-store

I'm travelling to the US soon and I would like to buy iPhone 7 (unlocked) from an Apple Store.  However, I live in Germany.

- Without AppleCare, can I go to to an Apple store here in Germany in case something happened to the iPhone?
- Are iPhones in the US are compatible with Germany's? Power/Energywise.
- Do I need extra/different adaptors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Yes, the service coverage of Apple products is worldwide. Though having AppleCare+ will save you some money because you may only have to pay for shipment of parts, etc. Refer to section 6.2 [here](http://www.apple.com/legal/sales-support/applecare/appforiphonenaen.html).
- Yes, as all Apple products come with standard power adapters and they're compatible anywhere voltage-wise, you may just have to use a universal power adapter in Europe. Otherwise, you can just use the USB to Lightning cable and use your own power adapter there in Germany.
- See answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is available, as I bought my iPhone in Korea and use it in China. It works well and is same as the Chinese version.